# How can I get authentication working for Guvnor on Tomcat?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, drools, drools-guvnor

I'm running Drools Guvnor on a Tomcat 6.0 server, but I'm having the worst time getting authentication working properly. This is for a small company, so I don't need many users, and LDAP would be massive overkill (and reportedly a humongous pain in the ass). My first thought was to tie it in to JAAS, which it has some kind of tools for. Unfortunately, I can't make heads or tails of the instructions I've found for using JAAS on Tomcat. From my reading, step one is "write your own JAAS implementation", which is obviously insane. (It probably doesn't help that I really don't know anything about Tomcat, and not much about server administration in general.)

So, screw JAAS, I said, I'll just use Tomcat's built-in basic authentication and forget about giving different permissions to different users. Basic HTTP authentication would normally be a terrible idea, of course, but the server's behind a firewall that blocks access from outside the office anyway, so it should be sufficient. So I added some users to `tomcat-users.xml`, then cracked open `web.xml` and added this:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>guvnor</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Guvnor web app</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Whole Guvnor app</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
        <role-name>guvnor</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

It took some trial and error, but it seemed to work fine. Going to the web app brought up a username/password challenge, logging in worked, and everything looked good. There was one big problem, though: The `KnowledgeAgent` in my rules engine implementation started getting hit with 401 errors when it tried to pull down the packaged rules. I changed the username and password in the `ChangeSet.xml` I'm using to a valid one, of course, but it still didn't work.

As far as I can tell, when I use a username/password that Tomcat likes, Guvnor's `DemoAuthenticator` looks at them, notices that the username and password are not the same, and refuses access. There's a line in `beans.xml` that appears to be loading `DemoAuthenticator`, but commenting it out doesn't seem to do anything. (I don't know why this doesn't happen to the web app.) The other possibility I've come up with is that neither setting `basicAuthentication`, `username`, and `password` nor adding the username and password to the URL is sending the authentication up in a format that Tomcat recognizes as basic HTTP authentication. I'm not really sure how to tell the difference. At this point I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I don't know what to do to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any advice?